# How to handle an Identity Provider that uses transient NameID

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I'm trying to use the Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2 middleware in my application. I've successfully logged in and registered my email address the first around, logged out, and tried to login again. The problem that I'm facing is that the NameID is used as the ProviderKey in ASP.NET Identity and I'm being asked to provide my email again as if I was logging in for the first time. While debugging as to why is this happening, I see that the call to:

```
signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: true, bypassTwoFactor: true);
```

returns {Failed}. Also, I've noticed that the ProviderKey is different from what's in the AspNetUserLogins table. How do I go about connecting the second login of the same external identity to the internal identity created on the first login?

Answer (score 0):

If the NameID is transient, it cannot be used as the provider key in Asp.Net Identity. The easiest way is of course to talk to the Idp and ask them to switch to a persistent NameID instead.

If that's not possible, check if there's any attribute that is fixed and would be suitable to use as a key. You can then override the `AcsCommandResultCreated` notification. In there, remove the existing NameIdentifier claim and create a new one from the attribute you want to use.